# Image overlapping over div

Tags: html, css

iam facing a small issue with overlapping .

Consider this html snippet

```
<html> 
  <head>
    div
    {
      width:100%;
      height:100px;
    }
    img
    {
      width:100%;
    }
    #div2
    {
      margin-top:-100px;
    }
  </head>
  <body> 
    <div id="div1"> 
      <img src=""/> 
    </div> 
    <div id="div2"> 
      some text 
    </div> 
  </body> 
</html>
```

I want to overlap a div2 over div1. As the code will overlap since margin-top of div2 equals height of div1. My problem is image is overlapping div2. What is the reason of this behaviour ?

And i don't want to give position absolute to the elements since this code will break the layout of the page if position absolute is used.

Thanks.

Comment: `z-index` is the property / term you need to look at.

Comment: okay i tried with giving z-index 10 for div1 and 20 for div2 still it is not working.

Comment: z-index only works on positioned elements

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Check this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/s1xxeza9/). As onetrickpony mentioned, need to be positioning the elements.

```
div
{
  width:100%;
  height:100px;
}
img
{
  width:100%;
}
#div1 {
z-index: 10;
position: relative;
}

#div2
{
position: relative;  
margin-top:-100px;
border: 1px solid #f00;
z-index: 20;
color: #fff;
font-weight: bold;
}
```

Comment: Thanks man..It was silly on my part and it solved my issue. The think i missed was style position relative for the div's .